# Erro ao colocar escala no mapa ggplot

Tags: r

Estou usando esse shape file para fazer um mapa: [link](ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/RJ/)

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)    
mapadf <- readOGR(dsn= "/rj_municipios", layer = "33MUE250GC_SIR")
    mapadf <-fortify(mapadf)
```

O mapa fica como eu quero, então eu tento colocar a escala usando o pacote ggsn

```
library(ggsn)     
country3 <-ggplot(data= mapadf, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
      geom_path() +
      coord_map("mercator") +
      xlim(-42.040,-41.973)+
      ylim(-23.015, -22.94)


country3+ ggsn:: scalebar(mapadf,x.min = -42.040, x.max = -41.973,
                  y.min = -23.015, y.max = -22.94,
                  dist=5, model='WGS84',
                  st.dist=.05, transform = TRUE,
                  dist_unit = "Km")
```

Ai eu recebo:

```
Error in maptools::gcDestination(lon = x, lat = y, bearing = 90 * direction,  : 
  subscript out of bounds

Warning message:
Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_text)
```

Tenho visto isso funcionar em todos os exemplos que eu encontro, comigo não funciona, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Não tenho como testar no momento, mas experimente remover `xlim()` e `ylim()` do mapa e *x.min*, *x.max*, *y.min* e *y.max* da `scalebar()`.

Comment: Fazendo isso eu perco o local do mapa que eu quero mostrar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como está cortando a área a ser plotada e indicando o conjunto completo de dados na `scalebar`, além do tamanho desta ser maior que a área exibida, recebe o erro de "fora dos limites". Precisa:

- reduzir o tamanho da barra de escala;
- remover a indicação ao *data frame*;
- especificar limites com uma folga para a plotagem

Além disso, precisa definir `group` na estética da geometria, não na global.

```
country3 <- ggplot(mapadf) +
              geom_path(aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
              coord_map("mercator") +
              xlim(-42.04, -41.973) +
              ylim(-23.015, -22.94)

country3 + scalebar(x.min = -42.04, x.max = -41.975,
                    y.min = -23.01, y.max = -22.94,
                    dist = 1, dist_unit = "km",
                    model = 'WGS84', transform = TRUE,
                    st.dist = .03)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]